# php uploads and zero filesize

Tags: php, forms, upload

I would so appreciate some help here please. I have been struggling without success for a full day to upload images to a shared host running Zeus (rather than apache--yes I know, they are changing!). The host blames the code yet wont tell me why "as they are not programmers" I have tried so many different version of the form script I am out of options. I have of course checked the upload limits on the php ini file configs (which I am not allowed to change by the host) and they are both 128meg. So it looks unlikely that is the cause. The outcome of the scripts is that we get to the final ''successfully loaded the file'' message but the files size loaded is zero (so there is nothing new in the target directory). I am relatively new to php so please do go easy on the jargon. Thank you.

Here are the two files>> First the form...

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="anewupload.php" method="POST">
Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and the php file refered to by the form...

```
<?php 
 $target = "uploads/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1;

 //This is our size condition 
 if ($uploaded_size >350000) 
 { 
 echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
 $ok=0; 
 } 

 //This is our limit file type condition 
 if ($uploaded_type =="text/php") 
 { 
 echo "No PHP files<br>"; 
$ok=0; 
 } 

 //Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error 
  if ($ok==0) 
 { 
  Echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
  } 

   //If everything is ok we try to upload it 
  else 
   { 
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
  { 
  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded    to..";
  echo $target;

 echo "..The uploaded file size is $uploaded_size";
  } 
 else 
  { 
  echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
  } 
  } 
 ?>
```

Comment: First make sure the `uploads` folder exists and has write permissions set to either `755` or `777`.

Comment: After submit, show us the output of `var_dump($_FILES)`.

Comment: Another thing I'm questioning is the fact that `$uploaded_size` has not yet been defined. You would need to use something like `if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] >350000)` or `if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] <350000)` etc. probably another reason why it's failing.

Comment: And your `$uploaded_type` is also another unassigned variable, so again, that too is making your code fail.

Comment: thank you gentleman, it was pleasure to hwave you respond. That was my first ever question and I am so impressed there are such nice people our there to talk to. I will do the var_dump($_FILES) right now. Regarding the point about defining max file size I do have this line of code inserted already. ...if ($uploaded_size >350000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the `uploads` folder exists and that is has write permissions set to either `755` or `777`

Plus, you have two unassigned variables, `$uploaded_size` and `$uploaded_type`, so that will fail.

You would need to use something like `if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] <350000)` etc. probably another reason why it's failing.

Give this a try, see if this works for you, it's what I use:

Modify `$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");` for permitted file extensions.

It will upload only if size is less than `350000`

**NOTE:** Change `<input name="uploaded" type="file" />` to `<input name="file" type="file" />` see form under handler code.

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 350000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Also change your form to this to reflect the PHP handler:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="anewupload.php" method="POST">
Please choose a file: <input name="file" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH. THAT WAS MY FIRST QUERY EVER ON THIS SITE. IN FACT MY FIRST EVER QUERY FROM ANY ONLINE COMMUNITY. YOU SOLVED MY PROBLEM WITH YOUR SUGGESTIONS AND THE CODE ABOVE. I CANNOT THANK YOU ENOUGH. BASED IN THE UK I WOKE UP THIS MORNING WORRYING ABOUT THE PROBLEM. THEN I PICKED UP YOUR SOLUTION WHICH WORKS 100% PERFECTLY. THANK YOU AGAIN.

Comment: @user2755309 You're welcome. Please click the checkmark under the arrows to accept as an answer. Am glad I could help.

Comment: Hi Fred. You must think the worse of me for needing to ask but where the devil are those arrows you mention (and is it possible for me to give you reputation points on here? - first time very happy user on here).

Comment: cor blime...they dont make finding that little devil easy do they Fred. Anyways all sorted. With a green arrow showing (I hope). Without question I will be using this service again. Really good. And again thank you!

Comment: @user2755309 *You're quite welcome.* - The same thing happened to me to at the beginning. StackOverflow should probably put a little note or make the arrow more in evidence. It's a good place though, where you can browse through questions and find answers at the same time. Will be more than happy to help should you have any other questions in the future mate, cheers!